# how to access first element of a struct array

Tags: c, arrays, struct

So I implemented the following method. The problem is that when I begin
searching the variableVector pointer I noticed that variableVector->variables
might not be pointing to the beginning variable element.

```
Variable* findVariable(VariableVector *variableVector,
        char *variableNameOfVariableToReturn) {
    if (variableVector->size < 1) {
        return NULL ; // since variableVector is empty
    }
    Variable *currentVariable = variableVector->variables;//<== HOW TO RESET TO BEGINNING???
    int numberOfVariablesInVariableVector = variableVector->size;

    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfVariablesInVariableVector; i++) {
        if (strcmp(currentVariable->variableName,
                variableNameOfVariableToReturn) == 0) {
            return currentVariable;
        } else {
            currentVariable++;
        }
    }
    return NULL ; // variable not found in variableVector
}
```

These are what my structs look like:

```
struct _Variable {
    char *variableName;
    char *arrayOfElements;
    int32_t address;
};
typedef struct _Variable Variable;

struct _VariableVector {
    int size; // elements full in array
    int capacity; // total available elements
    Variable *variables;
};
typedef struct _VariableVector VariableVector;
```

Also this is how I add a new variable:

```
bool appendVariable(VariableVector *variableVector, Variable *variable) {
    if (variableVector->size == variableVector->capacity) {
        return false;
    } else { // append since vector is not full
        int indexOfFirstEmptyElement = variableVector->size;
        memcpy(&variableVector->variables[indexOfFirstEmptyElement], variable, sizeof(Variable));
        //variableVector->variables[indexOfFirstEmptyElement] = *variable;
        variableVector->size++;
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: maybe `Variable *variables;` should be a `Variable **variables;`. As I understand, you want a pointer which points so somewhere where a lot you have saved a few `*variables`. Currently `*variables` just points to one `_Variable`.
`

Comment: How do you create/fill `variables`?

Comment: Don't start names with underscore `_`. Those are reserved for the compiler use.

Comment: @gumble Pointer to arrays **is** pointer to first member of the array in C. `Variable *variables` is fine.

Comment: I don't see problem with the current code. `Variable *currentVariable = variableVector->variables;` always gives first element of the array. Problem is somewhere else.